# How to use 2 variables in 1 argument in a R function with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to create a function in R which would allow to  to group a data framen according to 2 variables put in a single argument of my function.

My example :

```
library(dplyr)

myfunction <- function(vars=NULL) {
  
  starwars %>% 
    group_by(!!sym(vars)) %>% 
    summarise(stat=mean(height,na.rm=T))
  
}

# It works
myfunction(vars="gender")

# It doesn't work
myfunction(vars=c("gender","sex"))
```

Many thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For multiple arguments you can use `syms` with `!!!` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

myfunction <- function(vars=NULL) {
  starwars %>% 
    group_by(!!!syms(vars)) %>% 
    summarise(stat=mean(height,na.rm=T))
}
```

However `across` accepts string arguments so you can do this without any NSE :

```
myfunction <- function(vars=NULL) {
  starwars %>% 
    group_by(across(all_of(vars))) %>% 
    summarise(stat=mean(height,na.rm=T))
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately neither solution works with unquoted names, so it doesn’t follow the typical dplyr/rlang argument passing style.